# Save listings to excel file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list

I have printed the following output on screen representing results obtained in previous calculations.

```
import pandas as pd

lista_b = [['A', 'B'], ['E', 'F'], ['I', 'J'], ['M', 'N'], ['B', 'C'], ['F', 'G'], 
           ['J', 'K'], ['N', 'O'], ['C', 'D'], ['G', 'H'], ['K', 'L'], ['O', 'P'], 
           ['B', 'F'], ['F', 'J'], ['J', 'N'], ['C', 'G'], ['G', 'K'], ['K', 'O'], 
           ['D', 'H'], ['H', 'L'], ['L', 'P']]

lista_c = [110.6, 108.7, 108.7, 110.9, 70.2, 68.0, 68.0, 70.6, 93.4, 91.8, 91.8, 93.7]

print('index',3*' ','Nodes',9*' ','Values')
for i in range(len(lista_c)):
    
    print(f"{i+1:02}        {lista_b[i]}     {lista_c[i]:>6}")     

#data_save = pd.DataFrame(lista_c).to_excel('data_save.xlsx', header=False, index=False)
```

What I'm looking for is to save these results in an excel sheet so that they are displayed as follows:

[image]

I don't know if there is a way to print their respective headers as well, as shown by screen printing.

Best regards,

Comment: What happens to the other values in `lista_b`?

Comment: @Celius Stingher, For list b, I only take the first 12, or up to the length of list c, I do that with the loop that I defined, which is why the rest of the values not from 'list_b' I don't take them into account.

Comment: Ah, then you can check my answer, is almost the same as Quang Hoang, with this edit you mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given both `lista_c` and `lista_b` and your comment on how to deal with it, you can do the following to avoid using for loops:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'index':range(1,len(lista_c)+1),'Nodes':lista_b[:len(lista_c)],'Values':lista_c})
print(df)
```

This returns the exact desired output:

```
    index   Nodes  Values
0       1  [A, B]   110.6
1       2  [E, F]   108.7
2       3  [I, J]   108.7
3       4  [M, N]   110.9
4       5  [B, C]    70.2
5       6  [F, G]    68.0
6       7  [J, K]    68.0
7       8  [N, O]    70.6
8       9  [C, D]    93.4
9      10  [G, H]    91.8
10     11  [K, L]    91.8
11     12  [O, P]    93.7
```

Which you can then save to excel with:

```
df.to_excel('desired_file_location',index=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Nodes':lista_b, 'Values':lista_c})
df.to_excel('file.xlsx')
```

Note that your `lista_b` and `lista_c` has to have the same length. In the case they might have different lengths:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(lista_b, lista_c), columns=['Nodes','Values'])
```

Comment: I thought the same thing, but `lista_b` and `lista_c` don't have the same length

Comment: Yes, thanks for the observation. For that case then it would be advisable to establish a new list with the first 12 values of 'lista_b'? And in that way have the same lengths?

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable contributions, best regards.